# Blank Images on Safari Browser for Desktop and Iphone but opens fine on other phones and windows browsers

Tags: html, css, ios, bootstrap-4, safari

I am having issues with seeing images displayed on safari browser for both MAC and Iphones but these images opens just perfectly fine on windows browsers and android OS. I have used the latest version of bootstrap and still getting the same error.

Below are the latest bootstrap CDNs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

By the way, the images are being called from cloudinary and I can't seems to understand why it is showing all blank on safari browsers for both iPhone and mac.

[image: Display on safari for iPhone]

Comment: Could you provide some code? Or a link to your site?

Comment: here is the link http://www.pdtv6.com

Answer (score 0):

You are using the image format `.webp` in your `<img>`tags.
[WebP Format is not supported in Safari currently](https://caniuse.com/#search=webp)

Try to use another image format or create something like a fallback for your images.